# Change dataframe value if it is twice as high as corresponding control value

Tags: r, dataframe

In R, I have a dataframe with 30000+ rows that are data clusters and 100 columns that are the samples/controls that the data occurs in.

If any of the control values value is not 0, then the  values of sample that are lower than the **edit: twice the value of the** control(s) of that row must become 0.

The control value can be modified to 0 or remain the same: these columns will be removed after filtering the data.

The dataframe looks like this:

```
sampleID <- c('clust1', 'clust2', 'clust3')
sample1 <- c(50, 0, 70)
sample2 <- c(0,40,5)
sample3 <- c(10,20,0)
control1 <- c(10,2,0)
control2 <- c(0,30,0)
df <- data.frame(sampleID, sample1, sample2, sample3, control, control)

df
    ClusterID sample1 sample2 sample3 control control
    clust1    50      0       10      10       0  
    clust2    0       40      20      2        30
    clust3    70      5       0       0        0
```

The desired output should look like this:

```
df
    ClusterID sample1 sample2 sample3 control control
    clust1    50      0       0       0       0  
    clust2    0       0       0       0       0
    clust3    70      5       0       0       0
```

What I tried with lapply(unsuccesfully)

```
#list controls
neg_control = c("control1", "control2")

rows_to_replace = list()
sapply(neg_control, function(nc) {
  temp <- df[df[,nc] > 0, ]
  #go over values to filter on
  values <- temp[,nc]
  # go over the values and the rows
  sapply(1:length(values), function(i){
    # for every column check if the value is twice that of the control
    sapply(2:length(colnames(temp)), function(col){
    if (temp[i,col] < 2*values[i]){
        # if true, change that avalue to 0
        temp[i,col] <- 0}
  })
  # save row to variable
  rows_to_replace <- append(rows_to_replace, temps)
  })})
```

The last line produces the row I need, but I can't figure out how to tie it together into my desired output. This code returns 2 matrices, not my desired output.

I've not been working with R for very long and need to get this right for a bioinformatics project. I've been cracking my head over this and googling all day with no luck. Hope someone here can help!

**EDIT**: akrun his code works (after a small edit)

```
# control columns ans sample columns
controls = c('control1', 'control2')
samples = c('sample1','sample2','sample3')

# mcr = max control value for each row
mcr <- do.call(pmax, otu[controls])
#mcp = max control values that are positive
mcp <- mcr > 0 

# for each row change values that are lower than 2*max control value to 0
otu[mcp, samples][otu[mcp,samples] < 2*mcr[mcp]] <- 0
```

Comment: What are the control values in your example?

Comment: Are you check for corresponding 'sample', 'control' pairs.  In that case, there is no 'control' for 'sample3'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the condition showed

```
nm1 <- names(df)[startsWith(names(df), 'control')]
mx <-  do.call(pmax, df[nm1])
i1 <- mx > 0
nm2 <- grep("^sample\\d+$", names(df), value = TRUE)
df[i1, nm2][df[i1, nm2] < 2 * mx[i1]] <- 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Although the answer you proposed didn't to exactly what I needed, it was very helpful. I gave me enough direction to come up with my own solution (see edit).

Comment: I can checkmark your answer if you remove `[col(df[i1, nm2])]` from your answer, then it works exactly as intended. I found out that works and is much faster than what i thought of a week ago. Cheers.